# Highcharts dynamicly update legend with grouped values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to get the legend to show the grouped value for the series, and to dynamically update it when the range is changed.

By changing the range, I mean clicking on range selector, moving the navigator or zooming in/out.

I've managed to show the total when the chart is loaded. But I want to show only the total for the current range selected, not of the whole data.

I tried with a function on `labelFormatter`. I can access `this.yData`, which is all the data. But I can't access `this.groupedData` or `this.processedYData`, to get only the current data grouped. It gives me `undefined`.

But I suppose the best way is to use `redraw` on `events` to update the legend. But even with this I can't access the grouped values, only the total of all data.

Here is the fiddle with what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/3H3ac/

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of solutions to achieve that, one of them is to re-render label in `afterSetExtremes` event: http://jsfiddle.net/UaaZ3/

```
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function () {
                var chart = this.chart,
                    legend = chart.legend,
                    merge = Highcharts.merge;

                // force redraw each element in legend
                this.chart.isDirtyLegend = true;

                for (var i in legend.allItems) {
                    var item = legend.allItems[i];

                    item.legendItem.destroy(); // destroy previous label

                    item.legendItem = chart.renderer.text(
                        legend.options.labelFormatter.call(item),
                        legend.symbolWidth + legend.options.symbolPadding,
                        legend.baseline)
                    .css(merge(item.visible ? legend.itemStyle : legend.itemHiddenStyle)) 
                    .attr({
                        align: 'left',
                        zIndex: 2
                    })
                    .add(item.legendGroup); // add new label
                }
                this.chart.redraw(false); // redraw chart, just in case
            }
        }
    },
```

And `labelFormatter`:

```
        labelFormatter: function () {
            var total = 0,
                data = this.processedYData ? this.processedYData : this.yData; // series is rendered, or first render
            for (var i = data.length; i--;) {
                total += data[i];
            };
            return this.name + '- Total: ' + total;
        },
```

Also, for now you are using selected option in rangeSelector. Unfortunately for you, first is rendered legend, with series, then calculations for series are done. To avoid that, remove selected option, and in `chart.events.load` use `chart.setExtremes()` to force legend update.

EDIT:

To prevent error I developed better solution, see: http://jsfiddle.net/UaaZ3/3/

Formatter:

```
function getLegendFormat(serie) {
    var total = 0,
        data = serie.processedYData ? serie.processedYData : serie.yData; // series is rendered, or first try?
    for (var i = data.length; i--;) {
        total += data[i];
    };
    return serie.name + '- Total: ' + total;

}
```

AdterSetExtremes:

```
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function () {
                var chart = this.chart,
                    legend = chart.legend;

                for (var i in legend.allItems) {
                    var item = legend.allItems[i],
                        newText = getLegendFormat(item);

                    item.legendItem.attr({ text: newText })
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

labelFormatter:

```
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return getLegendFormat(this);
        },
```

Comment: Not sure why, but firebug fires a TypeError when moving the mouse over the legend. It only happens after changing ranges. It does not break the chart though, so I'm ignoring it. Other than that, it works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: See updated answer - another approach, and error doesn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can set useHTML as true in the legend, including formatter with class. Then catch setExtremes() function and calculate values. In the end, update legend items.

```
setExtremes:function(){
                var series = this.series,
                    total = 0;

                $.each(series,function(i,s){
                    total = 0;
                    for (var j = s.processedYData.length; j--;) {
                        total += s.processedYData[j];
                    };
                    total = Highcharts.numberFormat(total);

                    $('div.highcharts-legend-item').eq(i).find('.total').html(total);

                });
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3H3ac/14/

Comment: It is kinda buggy with the zoom selector. Try clicking on different ranges, at some point it starts showing odd values.